# PHP Calling class method from constructor not filling array

Tags: php

I have a very weird problem that when I call the method of a class from within the constructor I get as a result empty arrays, but when I call the method from the class instance it works fine.

Here is the code for loadxml.php:

```
include('XMLNode.php'); // this is a simple object class

class LoadXML
{
public $MyNodes = array();

public function __constructor($xmlFile)
{
    $this->getNodes($xmlFile);
}

public function getNodes($xmlFile)
{
    if (file_exists($xmlFile)) {
        $xmlNodes = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

        foreach ($xmlNodes->XMLNode as $key => $value) {
            array_push($this->MyNodes, $value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit('Failed to open xml file '.$xmlFile);
    }
}
}
```

Now in the main file if I make the call like this:

```
include('loadxml.php');

$nodes = new LoadXML('myXMLFile.xml');

print "<pre>";
print_r($nodes);
print "</pre>";
```

... the result looks like this:

LoadXML Object
(
    [MyNodes] => Array
        (
        )
)

If I make the call from the class instance like this and comment out the call to getNodes from the LoadXML constructor:

```
include('loadxml.php');

$nodes = new LoadXML();
$nodes->getNodes('myXMLFile.xml');

print "<pre>";
print_r($nodes);
print "</pre>";
```

I will get the correct output. What's happening? What am I doing wrong in the first approach? Am I missing something from the class constructor? I looked in the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/oop4.newref.php) and the call to the method seems legit from within the constructor.

Comment: I am actually trying to figure out why your script doesn't `exit` when you call `new LoadXML()`.  You haven't passed a parameter, yet you still call `getNodes()` in the constructor. In such a case, `file_exists()` would evaluate as false, causing the `exit`.  Does your code shown here accurately reflect the entire class structure and the tests you are performing?

Comment: @MikeBrant his constructor gets never called. He has to rename it to `__construct` before your described behaviour will be correct in the second example.

Comment: @Benjamin Haha. I was spending my time looking at the actually logic that I didn'y actually look at the name of the method.

Comment: LoL! the simples things kill me ... :) Thanks Benjamin!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try renaming your constructor to `__construct`

Comment: Thank you sir! Damn, I would have never thought of that. I would have expected php to give me an error or something ... Greatly appreciate your quick reply! :)